# Something's wrong with Leiningen

Tags: clojure, environment-variables, leiningen

I downloaded the windows installer for Leiningen and there didn't seem to be any issues, but when I start a Clojure REPL it doesn't recognise any Lein commands.

I thought the issue might be with my Enviroment Variables, but they all seem to be in order:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfnfZ.jpg

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lein is a DOS/command line program, not a Clojure REPL extension.

Just open a plain command line and type "lein"

Note that lein is able to start a clojure repl with "lein repl"

Answer (score 0):

There's still a problem with leiningen 2.5.1. the jar has been replaced by a zip, it was changed in the lein script but it has only changed after for lein.bat. So the thing will be good with version 2.5.2 of lein.bat file...
The installer doesn't have the change so it searches the jar... The same thing for the chocolaty lein package installer...

I've no accessible windows pc for now, but it should be around that.
We still search the guy who write the installer, @technomancy doesn't know him.

Normally you can download the zip file, and change the extension to .jar and put it in the self-install directory in the lein.bat directory. Verify witch version of the jar is called in the .bat. It chould be defined in the first lines as a variable.